# What is the (Empty) Column at Beginning of WPF Datagrid called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my example of a datagrid, as first column a small empty column is shown:

[image].

But only after I added items to the `ItemsSource`:

```
dgListings.ItemsSource = null;
dgListings.ItemsSource = listingViewModel.LoadedListings;
```

This column is created, it seems to be a specific elemet, if I click the header of it, all rows are selected:

[image]

This is my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgListings" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadedListings}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"         Width="*"   IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding listing_id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"   Width=".5*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding quantity}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"      Width="2*"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding title}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price"      Width="*"   IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding price}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency"   Width="*"   IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding currency_code}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How can I remove it and what is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called ***row headers*** and you can remove them by setting [`HeadersVisibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.headersvisibility?view=netcore-3.1) to `Column`, because by default this property is set to `All`, which includes row and column headers.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgListings" HeadersVisibility="Column" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadedListings}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```